# PHP - Global/Instance Variable

Tags: php, variables, symfony, instance-variables

I'm writing a `Command` for a web app running on `Symfony 2`. A [Command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) has a set structure and must be implemented as a `Class` with two set methods (`configure` & `execute`), plus any user-defined functions.

I want a few pre-defined variables that are accessible to all the functions, similar to how instance variable work in Java. How can I implement this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works using the [DependencyInjection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) component. DI is what you're looking for!

When using symfony2 standard if you extend `ContainerAwareCommand` - symfony will inject the container automatically ...

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
```

.. configure container-parameters in parameters.yml or config.yml

```
parameters:
    my_parameter: my_value
```

then access your container-parameters using

```
 $this->container->getParameter('my_parameter')
```

This way you can access those parameters from any "service" in your application as long as you have access to the container. You can even inject only the parameters which is advised as injecting the whole container is costly in terms of performance and makes testing harder.

Comment: You're stealing my speciality tag, I'll never earn more reputation :P (+1)